# Allow equations to span more than linewidth

Tags: equations, align, linewidth

I am using the align* environment in Latex (Beamer). I have a couple of equations there, but one is just slightly longer than the width of the slide, and the last bit of it stays outside the slide. Here is an example code:

```
\begin{frame}{sample frame}
    \begin{align*}
        X &= 3 \\
        Y &= A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+O
    \end{align*}
\end{frame}
```

the "+O" in the second equation would stay outside. If I could have the equations take just a bit more width in the slide than the regular linewidth, the second one would fit, instead of breaking the second one into two lines. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You might try applying `\mathrlap` to the X and Y to shove those lines left.  (Not tested.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a one-time case:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{sample frame}

\begin{align*}
\hspace*{-1.5em}
X &= 3 \\
\hspace*{-1.5em}
Y &= A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+O
\hspace*{-1.5em}
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Use `\frametitle`, not additional arguments to `\begin{frame}`.

[image]

However I'd prefer something on the following lines:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{sample frame}

\begin{align*}
X &= 3 \\
Y &= \begin{aligned}[t]A+B+C+D &+E+F+G+H+I+J \\
                               &+I+J+K+L+M+N+O
     \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! For some reason when I'm trying to align the equations by their beginning (leftmost) character rather than by the equal signs, this doesn't work. Do you know why? (this refers to your first suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Are you after the following frame looks?

[image]

By use of the `\medmath` of `nccmath` package (by which the font size used in equation is reduced for bout 30%) and `aligned` math environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{sample frame}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\[\medmath{
    \begin{aligned}
        X &= 3 \\
        Y &= A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+O
    \end{aligned}
            }
\]
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If reducing font size in equation, than you need to split long math term into two lines. For example by use of the `multlined˙ of ˙mathtools˙ package:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{sample frame}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{align*}
    X & = 3 \\
    Y & = \begin{multlined}[t]
                A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+ {}   \\
                    J+K+L+M+N+O
            \end{multlined}   
    \end{align*}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Ups, you actually ask how to locally enlarge `\textwidth` ... By use of `changepage` package this is simple:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{sample frame}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1em}{-1em}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{align*}
    X & = 3 \\
    Y & = A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+O
    \end{align*}
\end{adjustwidth}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The vertical space around your formula looks uneven in your adjustwidth example.

Comment: @mickep, you are right. Before `align?` should be inserted `\vspace{-\baselineskip}`. Corrected now.